# Rendering citations and references in HTML using PHP/Perl/Python/

Tags: looking-for-a-script, mediawiki, widgets, server-side-scripting, library

**Is there a PHP/Perl/Python/... library for picking citations out of an HTML file and rendering a nice list of references at the bottom, like in Wikipedia?**

I'm developing a website with heavily-sourced content, and I'd really like to have automatically-generated lists of formatted references, like in Wikipedia. (Check out their [philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy) page, and see how the superscript numbered citations interact with the references at the bottom. This is all dynamically generated, automatically ordered & linked.) They do it really well: the citations are linked to the references (which are backlinked to the citations), when you click on one of the links, the target is highlighted, etc. I'm tempted to build the site on MediaWiki just for this one feature, but it seems like overkill. Do I have any options?

Comment: What are your cons against MediaWiki and what will you use instead?

Comment: @Michael Against MediaWiki is my having to learn, customize, and depend on this big piece of software for a relatively small task. There's no "instead" yet, though I'd probably just write the HTML manually if it weren't for the pain of linking citations and keeping them updated.

Comment: So you have 3 choices: **a)** using media wiki and have this built-in feature **b)** use another free system and build that functionality yourself (which makes at least as much work as using media wiki) and **c)** do it all manually (which will result in way more work than using any existing system.

Comment: @Michael True. Do you know of another (smaller, lighter-weight) free system exists that has this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress, with the [Netblog plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/netblog/), is *almost* good enough for my needs. *Almost.* It doesn't generate [COinS](http://ocoins.info/) output, it doesn't have links to the footnotes, and it doesn't automatically link DOIs. Maybe this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll-citation and Jekyll-scholar (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858554/markdown-citations-in-octopress)) are extentions to Jekyll/Octopress, Ruby-based generators for static sites.